# Nested java collection generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'd like to call a method defined like

```
<T> void foo(Class<? extends Collection<T>>)
```

but there is no way the compiler let me pass

```
foo(ArrayList<Integer>.class);
```

What is the syntax to get the type class of a generic type?

I am implementing the common case where I have a

```
Map<Key, Collection<Value>>
```

and want to insert a value in the collection. If the collection does not exist it should create a new one and insert the value in it.
So far I have the following code, but with type safety warnings:

```
public static <K, V, C extends Collection<V>> boolean addToMappedCollectionNotNull(Map<K, C> aMap, K key, V element, Class<? extends Collection> type) {
    C collection = aMap.get(key);
    if (collection == null) {
        try {
            collection = (C)type.newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        aMap.put(key, collection);
    }

    return collection.add(element);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Comment: In method declaration line: Collection is a raw type. References to generic type Collection<E> should be parameterized

Comment: In collection = (C)type.newInstance(); line: Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#2-of ? extends Collection to C

Comment: I have no idea what your question is about, but reading it made me realize the solution to my own problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Boris [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106796/nested-java-collection-generics/6106936#6106936) you're probably looking for a MultiMap. But if you think that you have to transport the type information the [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) is a solution. Guice has a [TypeLiteral](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#vY65eMZAf-c/src/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.java&q=typeliteral%20package:http://google-guice%5C.googlecode%5C.com) implementation you can look at.

Comment: Type tokens for generic types would be ideal if implemented into the language. Super type tokens, like TypeReference<T>, are not so convenient but good enough. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Same goal can be achieved using Google's [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) library. There's an interface [`Multimap<K, V>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which associates a collection of values `V` to a key `K`.

> A collection similar to a Map, but
>   which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call [`put(K, V)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)
>   twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap
>   contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

`Multimap` is implemented by a `ListMultimap`, `SetMultimap` and `SortedSetMultimap` covering all possible needs for the collection of values `V`.

Answer (score 0):

> foo(ArrayList.class);

You cannot get the `class` of a parameterized type because there is [no exact runtime type representation](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ106).

You will have to re-design this to not put so much logic in one place. Maybe separate the part out that tests for a `null` `Collection` and the part the creates one in a different place, like a Factory.